# Using PartiQL with DAX for DYnamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax, partiql

If we use only PartiQL for Dynamodb calls, do the calls get automatically routed via DAX because we are using DAX cache also in front of some of our tables.

Basically how to use PartiQL along with DAX

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PartiQL does not use DAX behind the scenes.

If using PartiQL and needing a caching layer, I’d suggest using ElastiCache. It’s not seamless because you have to be aware the cache exists by calling to it directly but it would provide the necessary functionality.